# Graph/schematic generator for VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have a VHDL project that consists of a top level module containing other modules interconnected in various ways (and some of these modules are, themselves, containers for other modules).

Is there a utility that can generate a schematic illustrating the relationships between the modules? I'm not concerned with configuration details or architecture, just the inputs, outputs and nesting for each module in my project.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Program for drawing VHDL block diagrams?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156243/program-for-drawing-vhdl-block-diagrams)

Answer (score 2):

Xilinx PlanAhead has a very nice schematic viewer, which you can run at various stages of the implementation (i.e. post RTL analysis, post-synthesis, post-place and route). Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to do with the schematic.

If you just looking for a graphical presentation of your code, then you can use Altera synthesis tool, there you can get a RTL schematic view of your code which is pretty good, but if you have many hierarchies in your design, it take a long time to go over all the blocks. 
You can not edit the files, but it helps you understand the inter-connection between the different blocks in a quick and easy way.

There are tools such as EASE and HDL designer who can do this as well, but they cost a lot of money. I am not sure if Aldec can do this. But all those programs can import  the design into their graphical design environment, create symbols for each block and create an editable hierarchy for your design.
Synplify HDL Analyst can also do this for you. But I have never used it myself.

Here is an example of a design I imported into HDL Designer when i was working at TI France. The design was made of many blocks and this is only the top level (the quality is not very good, since I only made this for a quick review of the design environment.

[image: This is an image of a generated HDL schematic using Mentor's HDL Designer]

Comment: All I want is a diagram, and I don't really care about RTL level — I just want to see the entities with their ports, and which other entities they're connected too.

Comment: Well, if your design was in Verilog, you could be able to use the scrip VHIER in Perl.
But what you are asking for can only be done with commersial programs or a synthesis tool such as Xilinx ISE or Altera Quartus II. Try it out, you may find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

nSchema, which is part of [Verdi](http://www.springsoft.com/products/debug-automation/verdi) by SpringSoft(now acquired by Synopsys)